# How can I know I can use Viber to message new contact?

Tags: applications, viber-messenger, instant-messaging

I added a new contact and I am trying to understand if the person has Viber installed in his phone.
When i go to my Viber app and press the icon to compose a new message the person in question is not listed as part of the contacts that Viber shows.
When I go to my phone contact list and view the profile, I see a Viber icon.
So now I am confused. Does this mean that the person is using Viber or not?

Answer (score 2):

There are two things

1. The phone number you have entered must be the same phone number that your contact has used to register Viber
2. You need to Enable this option

   1. Click on **More**
   2. Select **Settings**
   3. Select **General**
   4. Ensure **Show all contacts** is ticked

I have checked it on my phone.

More information here

[1. Viber](https://help.viber.com/en/)

[2. itnursery](https://itnursery.com/viber-contacts-out-of-date-not-all-contacts-displayed-in-all-tab/)

Comment: Does it matter if the other person has me as a contact? Actually he does not have my phone number yet.

Comment: No that doesnt matter.

Comment: For your point (1) "must be the same phone", isn't that the same as not having viber installed? Or is it for the case of dual sim?

Comment: Dual sim or if they change their phone number